# handling JSOM clientcontext properly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, csom, jsom

I am trying out JSOM in Sharepoint 2016. I have made a WebPart containing the following code -

```
<div id="user-output"></div>
Movie Title: <input type="text" id="movie-title" /><br />
Description: <input type="text" id="movie-description" /><br />
<button type="button" id="submit-button">Add Movie</button>

<div id="movies-output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/ecmascript" src="../_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $('#submit-button').on('click', function () {
            var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var movies = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Movies');
            var movieCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
            var movie = movies.addItem(movieCreationInfo);
            movie.set_item("Title", $('#movie-title').val());
            movie.set_item("MovieDescription", $('#movie-description').val());
            movie.update();
            context.load(movie);

            context.executeQueryAsync(success, failure);
        });

        function success() {
            $('#movies-output').text('Created movie!');
        }

        function failure() {
            $('#movies-output').text('Something went wrong');
        }

        var upp;

        // Ensure that the SP.UserProfiles.js file is loaded before the custom code runs.
        //SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getUserProperties, 'SP.UserProfiles.js');
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', getUserProperties);
        //SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js', getUserProperties);

        function getUserProperties() {

            // Get the current client context and PeopleManager instance.
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

            upp = peopleManager.getMyProperties();
            clientContext.load(upp, 'UserProfileProperties');
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSuccess, onRequestFail);
        }

        // This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call succeeds.
        function onRequestSuccess() {
            $('#user-output').html('User Name: ' + upp.get_userProfileProperties()['PreferredName'] +
                '<br/>Department: ' + upp.get_userProfileProperties()['Department'] +
                '<br/>Designation: ' + upp.get_userProfileProperties()['Title'] +
                '<br/>Employee ID: ' + upp.get_userProfileProperties()['EmployeeID'] +
                '<br/>Branch Code: ' + upp.get_userProfileProperties()['branchCode']
                );
        }

        // This function runs if the executeQueryAsync call fails.
        function onRequestFail(sender, args) {
            $('#user-output').text("Error: " + args.get_message());
        }
    });
```

What this code does is -

1. Show user information in `user-output` div at document load ready
2. Saves a movie record when *Add Movie* button is clicked

However, for some reason, when *Add Movie* button is clicked, the code adds two movies instead of one. I think it has something to do with the `ClientContext`. But I am not sure why, or how to solve it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it happened, or if it's a bug, but while fiddling with the page source to find out why double posting was occurring,

I saw that my web part code was being rendered **twice** in the page. One part was visible, and another was under a hidden `div`.

However, when I went to edit page to delete the hidden web part, I couldn't. So I restored my page to the template version and re-added the web part.

After that the web part was working correctly. There were no problems with the code.